# Execute Windows command with spaces in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, firefox

My firefox is installed in *C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox*.

I amm trying to read the *firefox* version like this:

```
open (IN, "\"C:\\Program\ Files\\Mozilla\ Firefox\\firefox.exe\" --version|") or die "Couldn't fork - $!\n";   
my $aarray = (IN); 
print $fh "=========Array Content========> $aarray <====\n";

close(IN);
```

This is working perfectly. But, when I put path or command in a variable and try to execute, it fails saying "Couldn't fork"

```
my $ffox = 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe';

$ffox =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;  #Replacing single \ with double \\

$ffox =~ s/\ /\\ /g;   # Adding escape character before space 
chop($firefoxVer);  # remove last \n chr.

$ffox =~ s/$/\\\"/g; # With the below two commands, massaging the command to become

$ffox =~ s/^/\\\"/g; # "C:\\Program\ Files\\Mozilla\Firefox\\firefox.exe\"

$firefoxVer = $ffox.' --version|';  # Adding "version|" to the above command  
$firefoxVer =~ s/$/\"/g;     # and make it look like:

$firefoxVer =~ s/^/\"/g;   # "\"C:\\Program\ Files\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\firefox.exe\" --version|"

open (IN, $firefoxVer) or die "Couldn't fork - $!\n"; ==> Fails
```

Comment: chomp didn't help.. It is not executing the command and reading the outputstream of the command.

Comment: Are trying to get just the version, or trying to create a filehandle with the version as filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the backticks you can get the result directly without the `open`. Quote the command-line things that need to preserve their spaces:

```
use v5.10;
my $version = `"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" -version`;
say "version is $version";
```

If that directory is in your path, you don't need to fool around with that:

```
my $firefox = 'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox';
$ENV{PATH} .= ";$firefox";
my $version = `firefox -version`;
```