# Set environment variables by batch file called from perl script

Tags: perl, batch-file, console, environment-variables, command-prompt

Let's consider the following perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat");
system("msbuild");
```

The batch file invoked with the first `system` call is supposed to set up some environment variables so that the *msbuild* executable in the second `system` call can be found.

When I run this perl script I get the following error:

> 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So it looks like the environment variables set in the batch file are not made available to the context of the perl script.  What can I do to make this work?

**Note 1**

Running first the batch file from a console window and then running `msbuild` works fine. So the batch file works as expected and *msbuild* is actually available.

**Note 2**

My real-world perl script is much longer. This example here is a massive simplification which allows to reproduce the problem. So I cannot easily replace the perl script with a batch file, for example.

**Note 3**

The funny thing is: I've been using this perl script for one or two years without any problems. Then suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Is the first command (with spaces in the path) actually running correctly? See [my answer to Execute Windows command with spaces in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52049740/2766176) for instance.

Comment: Yes the first command seems to run fine. I can see that batch file printing some banner to the console.

Comment: You create a shell, execute a batch file which does stuff like change **that process's environment**, then exit the process you changed. You need to execute both commands in the same shell somehow.

Comment: And how would I do that in a perl script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your process has an associated environment which contains things like the search path.
- When a sub-process starts, the new process has a new, separate, environment which starts as a copy of the parent process's environment.
- Any process (including sub-processes) can change their own environment. They cannot, however, change their parent's process's environment.
- Running `system()` creates a new environment.

So when you call `system()` to set up your environment, it starts a new sub-process with a new environment. Your batch program then changes this new environment. But then the sub-process exits and its environment ceases to exist - taking all of the changes with it.

You need to run the batch file in a parent process, before running your Perl program.